# Using "IndexOf" on a List<T> of objects

Tags: c#, indexof

In my Visual Studio2019 C# console program (named 'codeTester') I have this object:

```
        public class ipData
        {
            private string ip;
            private string region;
            private string country;

            public ipData(string ip, string region, string country)
            {
                this.ip = ip;
                this.region = region;
                this.country = country;
            }
                    
            public string Ip
            {
                get { return ip; }
                set { ip = value; }
            }

            public string Region
            {
                get { return region; }
                set { region = value; }
            }
            public string Country
            {
                get { return country; }
                set { country = value; }
            }
            
        }
```

and I created a List of this object and add some data:

```
            List<ipData> ipInfo = new List<ipData>();
            ipInfo.Add(new ipData("192.168.0.199", "UT", "USA"));
            ipInfo.Add(new ipData("251.168.0.963", "NB", "CAN"));
```

Now I want to search the list on one of its fields so I ask the user for the data to search for:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter searh criteria: ");
            string searchparam = Console.ReadLine();
```

Next I want the index of the found item, if any:

```
int x = ipInfo.IndexOf(searchparam);
```

but this statement throws a design-time exception which says:

"*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'codeTester.Program.ipData'*"

So I've been stuck at this point for hours and all my searches have not yielded anything pertinent. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to search for exactly? The IP, the region, or the country? `ipInfo` is a `List<ipData>` so you should be passing an existing `ipData` instance to it to try and locate it in the list. It seems that you're actually trying to search by a string value, so perhaps `List<T>`'s `FindIndex` method is more aligned with what you want to do. Even so, you still have to decide what you're actually trying to search for and how that searching should work on a per-element level.

Comment: Try quering with a help of Linq: `var index = ipInfo.Select((item, index) => new {item, index}).FirstOrDefault(r => r.item?.Ip == searchParam)?.index ?? -1;`. Here I've assumed that `searchParam` should be compared with `Ip` property

Comment: I didn't think it mattered but I'm searching for the "region". User input would be something like "UT" and the search finds all the elements with a region == "UT". It could very well be that ```searchparam``` gets compared to any of the three fields. But for this case it's the 'region'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because the search parameter is expected to be of the same type as the element type of the list. In this case `ipData`.

You could use [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0) which accepts a [lambda expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp/) as parameter:

```cs
int x =
    ipInfo.FindIndex(ip => ip.Region == searchparam || ip.Country == searchparam);
if (x >= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine($"The IP address is {ipInfo[x]}");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

or you can use LINQ like this:

```cs
string ipAddress = ipInfo
    .FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.Region == searchparam || ip.Country == searchparam)?.Ip;
```

This will return a `null` string if no entry was found.

You can also have it return the whole record instead:

```cs
ipData data = ipInfo
    .FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.Region == searchparam || ip.Country == searchparam);
if (data != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Country = {data.Country}, Region = {data.Region}, IP = {data.ip}");
}
```

LINQ also allows you to return more than one result. E.g. you can return all data corresponding to one country like this:

```cs
var result = ipInfo.Where(ip => ip.Country == "USA");
foreach (ipData data in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Country = {data.Country}, Region = {data.Region}, IP = {data.ip}");
}
```

---

The C# naming conventions state the class names should be written in PascalCase. Another convention says that acronyms with up to two characters in length are written all upper case (`IP`). According to these conventions, the class name should be `IPData`.

See also:

- [Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) (Microsoft Docs)
- [C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ah - here's a problem. When I run this using the FindIndex method, I get the output as follows:

Enter searh criteria:
UT
**The IP address is codeTester.Program+ipData**

Comment: If you want to print the `ipData` object directly, you must [override its ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method).

Comment: Thank you! This suggestion solves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because IndexOf searches for the exact object in list. For it to work, you would have to pass ipData to it instead.

For this purpose, you should use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-5.0) or [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-findindex(system-predicate((-0)))).